# Aggregate columns by date (sum) Per customer

Tags: python, pandas

Peace,
I have the data in the following table:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vIAc.png)

I need to get to the point where each row represents a client and the columns are months and each month the amount spent.
[Something like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzE2P.png)

Thanks!!

Comment: Hi, you can try with a pivot table, `df.pivot(index='CustomerID', columns='InvoiceDate', values='TotalPrice')`. You may change  'CustomerID' column type (from float to string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['month'] = df.InvoiceDate.dt.to_period('M')
df.pivot_table(index='CustomerId', columns='month', values='TotalPrice', aggfunc='sum')
```